# For every 1:n rows, put dataset into a new group

Tags: python, data-manipulation, ranking

I would like to ask if there is any function similar to np.full that can be used on a dataframe.

For a context, I have many rows of data (simple example below) the following

| Number | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |

I want to split 1,2 into a new group so that I end up with

| Number | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |

| Number | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |

Where I can insert one group each time to my ranking model.

Is there any function that could achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: np.hsplit  should help:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html

Comment: @user9594794 numpy.vsplit worked perfectly for this! thank you